# How to store values (given by user via postmain) in the variables with POST method using Django restful services

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need help to store values for x , y, z into the variables with Django restful services. With the php this can be done with similar to below code.

```
var1 = $_POST['x'];
var2 = $_POST['y'];
var2 = $_POST['z'];
```

I have started learning Django (mainly Restful API) and easily learned to do many other things (which is not that easy to do with PHP) with Django such as insert, del, update data configured swagger and admin but I did not find a way to store value in variable. I want to store these variables to 'return' the kind of data that is being requested (these variable will have value something like that).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand your question, you are trying to fetch POST data in your view.  So you can access the data from the request object in your view class, for eg:

```
class YourView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        var1 = data['x']
        var2 = data['y']
        var3 = data['z']

        # do something with these variables....

        # or if you have serializer class
        ser = YourSerializer(data=request.data)

        .....
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: request.data in case of raw data is not correct. you need to distinguish here between Django's HttpRequest and Rest Frameworks's Request - with rest frameworks request - .data is parsed content of request body - including file and non file inputs. so good way to access post in rest framework view is using .data

Answer (score 0):

In the rest frameworks's apiview, you can access your data using `request.data`

request.data is parsed content of the request body and includes file and non-file inputs as well.

doc: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/

Note : good to be aware what is the difference between  Django's HttpRequest class and rest framework's Request class ( see in the doc link mentioned above ).